# simple htaccess RewriteRule or redirect doesnt work properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Trying to implement a simple .htaccess redirect
none of these work, any idea how to fix ?

```
RewriteRule ^/en/?productsublayout=products_horizon http://www.example.com/en/  [R=302,L]

Redirect 301 /en/?productsublayout=products_horizon http://www.example.com/en/
```

Comment: try this : http://serverfault.com/questions/773999/htaccess-301-redirect-does-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the documentation of mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), as your code has two common problems, both which already have been addressed in the documenation.

> **Per-directory Rewrites**
>
> [..]
>
> - The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, a Pattern with `^/` never matches in per-directory context.

and

> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the `%{HTTP_HOST}`, `%{SERVER_PORT}`, or `%{QUERY_STRING}` variables respectively.

Besides this, keep in mind that the first argument of `RewriteRule` is a regex. The `?` character has a special meaning in a regex.

---

You have to correct it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^productsublayout=products_horizon$
RewriteRule ^en/$ /en/? [R=302,L]
```

Alternatively, if you have a recent version of Apache, use the `QSD` flag instead of a trailing `?` behind the rewrite part.